# How to copy data and build stand-alone version of Apache IoTDB from an existing cluster?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I now have a cluster using Apache IoTDB Version 1.0.1. I want to copy the data and build a stand-alone IoTDB server in another environment. How can I do this? Any easy way to copy data between different IoTDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try copy tsfile in the original cluster and then load it in the new Apache IoTDB server. The file format for different IoTDB servers are all the same, so you can directly copy the data files you want to different IoTDB servers.